# NullPointerExceptionAndroidStudio

Tags: android

I am trying to create a list view, I tried to override `getView` method of the adapter but I am stuck with a problem. I will be glad if someone can point out the mistake.

Code:

```
    class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
    TaskAdapter(Task[] tasks) {
        super(TaskActivity.this, R.layout.task_list_layout,           R.id.task_item_name, tasks);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      convertView=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


        Task task = getItem(position);
        TextView taskName = (TextView)        convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_item_name);
        taskName.setText(task.getName());
        CheckBox checkDone = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_item_done);
        checkDone.setChecked(task.isDone());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
Logcat: 02-18 13:51:55.772 2789-2789/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.dell.taskit, PID: 2789
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                                                     at com.example.dell.taskit.TaskActivity$TaskAdapter.getView(TaskActivity.java:112)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1366)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1662)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix some grammar. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

`Task task = getItem(position);`
I think the `task` you got is null.
Check it.

Answer (score 2):

The array you pass to an `ArrayAdapter` must not contain any `null`s. Your `Task[] tasks` has at least one `null` in it.